# Delete extra record from destination index while copying from source index with elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm workiing with elastic search queries where I got the issue like copying records from one index to another index with same mapping and type. But, index1(source) is having less records (ex : 2) than index2(destination ex: 3). Now my requirement is to copy records from source index to dest index, and that extra one record(id:3) in destination index should be removed. I've made some trails using the [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/docs-reindex.html) query in elasticsearch, but it didn't work for me.

Any kind of help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

There should be better/easier ways to do via painless scripts but it is something I haven't tried yet.

Again I am assuming, your documents doesn't contain any **timestamp** field that keeps a track of when document has been created/updated, otherwise you can execute [Delete By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) using timestamp, once you **reindex** from source to destination.

The below technique makes use of [Ingest API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest-apis.html) and [Reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) feature of elasticsearch

Let's say you have

- source index - indexA
- dest index - indexB

Create two ingest pipelines

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/pipeline_one
{
  "description" : "pipeline from indexB to intermediate index",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "set" : {
        "field": "tempField",
        "value": "default"
      }
    }
  ]
}

PUT _ingest/pipeline/pipeline_two
{
  "description" : "pipeline from indexA to intermediate index",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "set" : {
        "field": "tempField",
        "value": "update"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Reindex from indexB to temporary indexC.

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "indexB"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "indexC",
        "pipeline": "pipeline_one"
    }
}
```

Reindex from indexA to temporary indexC

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "indexA"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "indexC",
        "pipeline": "pipeline_two"
    }
}
```

By doing so, now you know that the documents which are not needed could be deleted by doing delete by query, and if the value of **tempField** is still **default**.

```
POST indexc/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "tempField": "default"
    }
  }
}
```

At this point you can go ahead and delete destination index.

Recreate the destination index(do take a back-up first) and create the below pipeline to be used from intermediate index to destination, while also removing the field tempField so as to preserve your mapping.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/pipeline_three
{
  "description" : "pipeline from intermediate to destination index",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "remove" : {
        "field": "tempField"
      }
    }
  ]
}


POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "indexC"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "indexB",
        "pipeline": "pipeline_three"
    }

}
```